# Swift UIAlertController Class Controller for Reviews

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I want to separate this code from the GameScene. I want to be able to use one class to run the entire "RequestReview" suite of functions. It should start by running the initial function which displays a UIAlertController asking the user if they like the game. Depending on the response to that alert another alert may be shown to request a review or feedback via email.
My question is how to write this class and what to subclass it under. I want it to be self contained so that I may simply present the first alert from the GameScene. I am imagining something like:

```
//GameScene.swift
`let review = RequestReview()`
`self....present(review)


//RequestReview.swift
Import UIKit

Class RequestReview : ___? {
  func doYouLikeIt() {...}
  func leaveReview() {...} //if yes
  func leaveFeedback() {...} //if no
}
```

Comment: MY suggest is use third party lib like [Armchair](https://github.com/UrbanApps/Armchair) or [iRate](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iRate)

Comment: I would like to learn to code this piece myself, simply to get better at Swift